Pirate Treasure movie of the 70's or 80's
I'm trying to find a movie I watched as a child. Here are the details I can remember.

Possibly a Disney produced feature - but not 100% sure
Was a group of kids following clues which lead to a pirate treasure.
One of the clues involved a model pirate ship that had a crows nest on it.  When they got the model out the crows nest portion of
the model came away revealing a scroll with another clue on it.
Another Possible clue involved a lantern, and possibly a spy-glass
One of the main characters was a girl with pig tails
The movie had the production style of the Apple Dumpling Gang or Savannah Smiles, The Watcher in the Woods.
The treasure was located in a wall or basement floor (potentially)
Definitely not the Goonies - I'm pretty sure this movie was older. 
An old man helped the young kids with the riddles - I think he had a white beard and a captains hat.


Possible duplicate of Kids find pirate treasure map

I'm going out on a limb and saying this could be Pippi in the South Seas.
The main character is Pippi and she has very distinct pig tails:

It was made in the 1970's, so that fits your time frame. 
